# Where can you find

Tags: lateral-thinking

- A deadly river (but not today)
- A monarchy ran by animals
- A giant kitchen appliance

Contrary to many answers I received, this place, sadly, does not exist in real life.

**Big Hint:**

> All three statements refer to a connected world.

**Very Big Hint:**

> The river is not deadly due to a special occasion.

**Final Hint:**

> Why is the kitchen appliance big? To hold big things of course!

Comment: Is the second line referring to a Zbanepu Ohggresyl?

Comment: @Joe-You-Know No, it's not

Comment: Could this maybe need the [tag:knowledge] tag, if it potentially has to do with movies, TV shows, etc.?

Comment: no, in fact this is something lots of Puzzle SE viewers know about :) It's right up their alley, after all.

Comment: Just a thought, is the second line related to a rot13(orr uvir)? Thanks.

Comment: No, keep thinking :) one of the answers accidentally got the right idea for the second line actually.

Comment: This is pretty clever, but you're veering close to the line where "riddle" ends and "trivia question" begins (a line you probably don't want to cross, as pure trivia dressed up as a riddle is probably [off topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5160) here). Riddles should be forward-solvable from information they contain, not exercises in "guess what the setter was thinking", and should contain all the information needed to solve in the initial post (not tacked on later as a "hint"). Your other riddles have been great, but this one feels a little too "guess what I'm thinking" for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can find them all in

> A joke/riddle
>  Each of the answers refers to a part of a classic lateral thinking puzzle, as explained [here](http://jonathanbecher.com/2016/03/13/the-giraffe-in-the-refrigerator/)

A deadly river (but not today)

> Q: You need to cross a river but it is inhabited by crocodiles. You don’t have a boat but you do have a refrigerator. What should you do?
>  A Swim across, as the crocodiles are all at the lion's conference.

A monarchy ran by animals

> Q: The Lion King is hosting an animal conference. All of the animals attend, except for one. Which animal does not attend?
>  A: The elephant in the refrigerator

A giant kitchen appliance

> Q: How do you put a giraffe into a refrigerator?
>  A: Open the door, put in the giraffe, and close the door.
>  Q: How do you put an elephant into a refrigerator?
>  A: Open the door, take out the giraffe, put in the elephant, and close the door.

Comment: That’s a bingo!

Comment: The answers should probably be in reverse order though.

Comment: It appears that this puzzle has a significant requirement on prior knowledge / trivia. :/

Answer (score 11):

I can find them on

> Amazon

which is

> Amazon river, Amazon rainforest, and Amazon.com

Comment: You beat me to it. +1

Comment: well, why should the Amazon river not deadly today? Wrong answer :)

Comment: how is that a kitchen appliance?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D It doesn't say "is", it says "where", and Amazon.com could certainly allow you to purchase a large kitchen appliance.

Answer (score 4):

Probably

> in disney films

A deadly river (but not today)

> in hercules

A monarchy ran by animals

> in the lion king

A giant kitchen appliance

> in mickey and the beanstalk

Comment: Wrong :) Again, why should the river not deadly today?

Comment: because rot13(va gur svyz urephyrf qvq abg qvr rira vs ur qvirq va gur fglk gb trg Zrt onpx)

Comment: Well, you should also be able cross the river in the riddle too ;) also, a big hint: all three questions refer to one connected world.

Comment: Also, one of your answers accidentally was the correct one :) figure out which one is it and go from there

Answer (score 3):

It's a stretch but:

> Deschutes County, OR

A deadly river (but not today)

> [Lava River Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lava_River_Cave) Located in Deschutes, once this cave was deadly but not today.

A monarchy ran by animals

> Possibly [Lions Lake](https://oregon.hometownlocator.com/maps/feature-map,ftc,1,fid,1123117,n,lions%20lake.cfm), related to how Lions are kings.

A giant kitchen appliance

> [Newberry Volcano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newberry_Volcano), A volcano (Giant stove?)

Comment: You got the lion correct :) But no, this is not the answer, for the river is usually deadly but not deadly today.

Answer (score 2):

This is a shot in the dark here, but are they all in

> The Pride Lands from [The Lion King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion_King)?

I'm sure my responses are wrong here, but here it goes:

A deadly river (but not today)

> Is this referring to the watering hole where Simba sings, "Oh I just can't to be King" and Zazu is almost killed? Or perhaps the Elephant Graveyard?

A monarchy ran by animals

> The kingdom is run by Lions

A giant kitchen appliance

> Is this referencing Pride Rock, which may resemble a giant can opener?

Hint:

> All three statements refer to a connected world. These are all in the same workd

Also, referring to one of the comments you made,

> one of the answers accidentally got the right idea for the second line actually, which refers to Kant1's answer that a monarchy ran by animals was referring to the lion king.

Comment: Hmm, good guess, but notice how the riddle is tagged 'lateral-thinking' ? Also, quite a reach with your third statement there :)

Comment: I thought that was a pretty lateral way of thinking with the last clue.

Answer (score 0):

A deadly river (but not today)

> [Lake Albert](http://www.oregonlive.com/lake-abert/) (it is dried up now)

A monarchy ran by animals

> Lion's Lake - from Gustavo Gabriel

A giant kitchen appliance

> Possibly [mount hood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Hood), as in a [kitchen range hood](https://www.build.com/range-hoods/c109153)

For the title "Where can you find"

> Oregon